# Exclude specific urls from redirection via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have redirected old urls to new ones via htaccess.

```
Redirect 301 /index.php https://new-url.com/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/jewelry/armschmuck/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/schmuck/armschmuck/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/jewelry/halsschmuck/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/schmuck/halsschmuck/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/jewelry/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/schmuck/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/fashion/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/fashion/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/living/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/living/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/yoga/yogafashion/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/yoga/yoga-kleidung/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/yoga/yogamatten/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/yoga/yoga-matten/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/yoga/yoga-dvds-downloads/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/yoga/yoga-downloads/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/yoga/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/yoga/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/geschenkgutschein/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/gutscheine/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/fashion/sale-fashion/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/sale/sale-kleidung/
Redirect 301 /produkt-kategorie/jewelry/sale-jewelry/ https://new-url.com/produkt-kategorie/sale/sale-schmuck/
Redirect 301 /agb/ https://new-url.com/agb/
```

But I need some old urls to be excluded from that list, for example

```
https://old-url.com/?sab-document=20198&_wpnonce=cea2279225
```

Is it possible to exclude all urls starting with `https://old-url.com/?sab-document` ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes it's possible with `mod_rewrite` .

Comment: can you describe it more detailed please?